# Both receive and send in same select case

Tags: go

I've needed to forward the results of one channel to another. I used something like this:

```
for {
        select {
        ...
        case ch2 <- (<-ch1):
        ...
        }
}
```

This seems to work perfectly, but what exactly happens here? Does the select statement select on the receive or send operation or both?

I know a select statement can select on either individually:

```
select {
    case ch <- v:
}
```

```
select {                                                                         
    case v = <- ch:
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From the docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements):

> For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering the "select" statement. The result is a set of channels to receive from or send to, and the corresponding values to send. Any side effects in that evaluation will occur irrespective of which (if any) communication operation is selected to proceed. Expressions on the left-hand side of a RecvStmt with a short variable declaration or assignment are not yet evaluated.

Meaning that:

```
case ch2 <- (<-ch1):
```

Will block *immediately* on the receive from `ch1`, and then the `select` will control whether the send on `ch2` happens or a different `case`.

Hymns For Disco put it very well; the `select` treats it as `ch2 <- <something>`, where `<something>` is evaluated on entering the `select`.

It also has the side effect of consuming and discarding a value from `ch1` if that `case` doesn't end up being the one selected.

Comment: In other words, the `ch2 <- (...)` is seen as the actual send/receive statement as far as the case is concerned, while the `<-ch1` is a generic expression that has to be evaluated immediately.

Comment: @eNV your code doesn't wait for `routine` to do anything. Also, you can close an open channel any time. Closing doesn't need to be matched with a receive operation.

Answer (score 2):

As [Adrian answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67592125/1256452), this is *definitely* the wrong way to do it.  If you'd like to receive-and-forward data until some quit channel says to quit, you want this, or something similar:

```
func copyInputUntil(output, input chan T, quit chan struct{}) {
    for {
        var v T
        // wait for input value, or quit
        select {
        case <-quit: return // maybe: close(output), too (via earlier defer)
        case v = <-input:
        }
        // wait to send it
        select {
        case <-quit: return
        case output <- v:
        }
    }
}
```

This can be spun off as its own goroutine.  It's not very realistic and of course this is inefficient: you're better off just getting the sender to send directly to the right channel, rather than having this silly goroutine in between.

Still, I turned this all into a complete example on the Go playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/ojtq3ljuxyj).