# Pattern to avoid nested selects with repeated cases

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm reading the Concurrency in Go book from O'Reilly and found this code example:

```
doWork := func(
    done <-chan interface{},
    pulseInterval time.Duration,
) (<-chan interface{}, <-chan time.Time) {
    heartbeat := make(chan interface{})
    results := make(chan time.Time)
    go func() {
        defer close(heartbeat)
        defer close(results)
        pulse := time.Tick(pulseInterval)
        workGen := time.Tick(2 * pulseInterval) // this just creates workload
        sendPulse := func() {
            select {
            case heartbeat <- struct{}{}:
            default:
            }
        }
        sendResult := func(r time.Time) {
            for {
                select {
                case <-done:
                    return
                case <-pulse:
                    sendPulse()
                case results <- r:
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        for {
            select {
            case <-done:
                return
            case <-pulse:
                sendPulse()
            case r := <-workGen:
                sendResult(r)
            }
        }
    }()
    return heartbeat, results
}
```

It seemed very strange that two select statements were being used for a simple heartbeat. Then I understood that the reason behind this is that sendResults SHOULDN'T block trying to send a result to the `results` channel. If nobody is receiving from that channel, it will effectively block the goroutine and stop sending the heartbeat.

Then I thought... Why didn't they code it like this then?

```
doWork := func(
    done <-chan interface{},
    pulseInterval time.Duration,
) (<-chan interface{}, <-chan time.Time) {
    heartbeat := make(chan interface{})
    results := make(chan time.Time)
    go func() {
        defer close(heartbeat)
        defer close(results)
        pulse := time.Tick(pulseInterval)
        workGen := time.Tick(2 * pulseInterval) // this just creates workload
        sendPulse := func() {
            select {
            case heartbeat <- struct{}{}:
            default:
            }
        }
        for {
            select {
            case <-done:
                return
            case <-pulse:
                sendPulse()
            case results <- <- workgen:
                fmt.Println("Send result")
            }
        }
    }()
    return heartbeat, results
}
```

And realized that it is because if workgen has an available item and I read it but then nobody is reading from results, the workgen item will be lost.

*Question*

**Is there any other pattern to avoid these nested selects that have to repeat all the cases not to miss a value?**

*Thoughts*

Wouldn't all these problems be solved IF a select statement first validated that the results channel is waiting to receive a value instead of executing the right hand expression first?

In other words, if I have this `results <- <- workgen`, it would be better if the select said "hey, nobody is reading from results, let's not try to evaluate <- workgen". This seems like a very particular design choice for me and I think it is what makes a lot of nested selects necessary to begin with.

I think a case should first try to evaluate if the channels that are in the expression are ready to receive or send data, and then execute the expressions.

Comment: It does loose workgen items and it doesn't block the select statement. I wrote the code and tested it. Can you verify please? I'm pretty sure of what I tested.

Comment: This pattern `results <- <- workgen` won't work how you want because the select statement is only going to be concerned about the `results <- x` part, while the `<-workgen` result will be evaluated immediately (and discarded if `results` isn't ready). See [Both receive and send in same select case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67592031/11424673)

Comment: "**a case should first try to evaluate if the channels that are in the expression are ready to receive or send data**". The problem is that this information is only useful when coherent. If you see that if you see that A is ready, and then you see that B is ready, that doesn't necessarily mean that A and B are, or ever were ready at the same time. The runtime could theoretically solve this, but the solution might be overly complex or create a lot of noise in the scheduler.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco yeha, you're right. A solution for that problem would be extremely complex. Also, let's say that all the channels in the expression are ready. By the time the subexpressions are evaluated, maybe one or multiple channels are no longer available (ready to read and send).

Answer (score 1):

Use temporary variables for `workgen` and `results` in the select. Set these variables to `nil` or the original values depending on the current state.

Setting the variables to nil disables the branch of the select because channel operations on nil channels block forever.

```
    workGenT := workGen
    var resultsT chan time.Time
    var result time.Time
    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            return
        case <-pulse:
            sendPulse()
        case result = <-workgenT:
            workGenT = nil
            resultsT = results
        case resultsT <- result:
            resultsT = nil
            workGenT = workGen
        }
    }
```

Because only one of `workGenT` and `resultsT` are non-nil, the code above has two states:  The program is either waiting to receive a result or waiting to send a result.

Comment: Wow, this is such a clever pattern. Not just to solve this specific problem, it can be applied in so many places. This is basically saying "a case from a select statement can shutdown or reactivate other cases from the same statement". Beautiful. Also, I just learned the behavior of nil channels in select statements, I thought they'd panic.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple and similar pattern.

```golang
func hBeatTicker(ctx context.Context, ch chan<- struct{}, t time.Duration) {
    tick := time.NewTicker(t)
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            close(ch)
            tick.Stop()
            return
        case <-tick.C:
            ch <- struct{}{}
        }
    }
}

func workGen(ctx context.Context, ch chan<- time.Time, t time.Duration) {
    tick := time.NewTicker(2 * t)
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            close(ch)
            tick.Stop()
            return
        case ch <- <-tick.C:
        }
    }
}

func do(ctx context.Context, d time.Duration) (<-chan struct{}, <-chan time.Time) {
    heartbeat, results := make(chan struct{}), make(chan time.Time)

    go workGen(ctx, results, d)
    go hBeatTicker(ctx, heartbeat, d)

    return heartbeat, results
}
```

Comment: Ok, breaking it into two goroutines makes them independent and helps avoid that repeated code BUT, I'm just wondering here WHY do we need a healthcheck in a goroutine? Like, in which scenario could it "stop" working in order for a client to say "hey that routine is no longer healthy"? And after answering that question, would the purpose of the healthcheck be affected by this strategy of breaking the work and the healthcheck appart?

Comment: Suppose workGen is doing some work and after a while, there's an error and you'd like to stop and even signal a heartbeat generator to stop sending healthy beats. So, when the error comes, you can cancel the context or use another channel for this purpose.