# Goroutine deadlock in select case statement for simultaneous read and write of nil channel

Tags: go, concurrency, deadlock

The below example code is a boiled down version of a real world issue I'm experiencing in a project I am working on. I can solve the issue trivially (see code comments), but I'd like to understand why it isn't working as expected in the first place.

My expectation is that the `case w <- <- r:` statement should simply do nothing until both w and r are non-nil channels. In practice, however, this is causing the program to deadlock. My intuition is that the underlying select logic isn't able to handle this scenario where both channels are nil, perhaps because it *must* grab a value from the `r` channel before it can quietly wait to write to `w`. I would appreciate any insight.

I spent a fair bit of time on search engines and SO search trying to find a clue, but haven't been able to get the right combination of keywords that would shed any light.

Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/qw2wEsKys6F

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func waiter(reader, writer chan string, readerReady, writerReady chan struct{}) {
    // Nil channels block indefinitely, and will effectively cause the select to ignore case statements that use them
    var r, w chan string

    // var passThrough string
    for {
        select {
        // I want this to be ignored/skipped until both channels are ready
        // Right now it causes a deadlock
        case w <- <-r:
        // I can solve this trivially like so
        // case passThrough = <-r:
        //  fmt.Println("Wrote to passThrough:", passThrough)
        // case w <- passThrough:
        //  fmt.Println("Read from passThrough")
        case <-readerReady:
            fmt.Println("Reader is ready")
            r = reader
        case <-writerReady:
            fmt.Println("Writer is ready")
            w = writer
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    reader := make(chan string, 0)
    writer := make(chan string, 0)
    readerReady := make(chan struct{}, 0)
    writerReady := make(chan struct{}, 0)

    go waiter(reader, writer, readerReady, writerReady)

    go func(reader chan string) {
        reader <- "This should work when ready channel is tickled"
    }(reader)
    go func(writer chan string) {
        fmt.Println("Pulled from writer:", <-writer)
    }(writer)

    readerReady <- struct{}{}
    writerReady <- struct{}{}

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

Comment: You cannot wait for `<-r` and also somehow know that `w <-` will succeed, since you can't test for the latter until the former completes.

Comment: I was also puzzled. And the "This question already has answers here" link doesn't explain anything to me :(
Here is an even more minimized example: https://go.dev/play/p/gu1xHRf2wQB

Comment: This one works as expected, though: https://go.dev/play/p/KO3iF_jLHxJ

Comment: Thank you for the links to similar questions, and the more minimized example.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now what's going on. Please, look at this example: https://go.dev/play/p/VHqP_51R4VH. The `select` statement is only smart enough to understand that the first channel (`w`) is blocked. It doesn't treat the second channel (`r`) as a channel, actually; it tries to evaluate the `<-r` expression as any other expression and freezes :) I think that it is wrong to mark this question as a duplicate; at least with the link provided. The link leads to a different question. Please, consider reopening this question :)

Comment: And here is the ultimate proof that `select` evaluates the expression even if it cannot use the channel: https://go.dev/play/p/9Fk5UmgF2E1. That was an interesting question, thanks :)

Comment: Ups. I was wrong. Actually, this link is OK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67592031/both-receive-and-send-in-same-select-case :) The most voted answer has the same explanation.